# To do list example doesn't work for me

Tags: java, android

The following example doesn't work in the right way for me. As per the code, it should add the entry in the ListView when "ENTER" key is pressed. But it just enters the new line in the EditText field and doesn't really add the entry in the ListView. I don't get any error while running the application.
Here's my Activity and XML file.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.todo_list;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Inflate your view
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// Get references to UI widgets
ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);

// Create the array list of to do items
final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
// Create the array adapter to bind the array to the listview
final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                              todoItems);
// Bind the array adapter to the listview.
myListView.setAdapter(aa);

myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
        {
          todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
          aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
          myEditText.setText("");
          return true;
        }
      return false;
    }
  });
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="New To Do Item"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="427dp" >
    </ListView>
```

Comment: todoItems.add( myEditText.getText().toString()); use this one

Comment: your missing public the opening flower bracket void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {. just tried it out. it works you have not placed the the opening and closing curly braces properly i gues

Comment: Sorry, my bad, edited the post.

Comment: @jimmy0251 it works fine for me tested it on emulator

Comment: @sunil It doesn't work !!

Comment: @jimmy0251 here's the snap shot of my emulator after trying your code http://tinypic.com/r/97nx1x/5

Comment: @Raghunandan It adds new line when enter is pressed. I think I messed any other file of the project.
Surprisingly, The project which I downloaded from the Author's website contains the same code as mine and it works for me.

Comment: @jimmy0251 i don't know why it does not work for you coz the same code works on my emulator. i tried entering something and pressed enter key and the text is displayed in listview. Also what i see in the above code looks fine to me

Comment: check my screenshot : http://i42.tinypic.com/35j9ef5.png

Comment: Okay got it, It works only if you use hardware keyboard in emulator. It doesn't if you use software keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first check whether myEditText.setOnKeyListener is getting fired when you pressing Enter.

If yes then add these properties in your edittext xml

```
ndroid:singleLine="true"
android:lines="1"
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: No, It isn't getting fired when I press Enter. Any idea ?